# Unsatisfiable error installing QIIME in conda environment glibc==2.31=0

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda, qiime

I've been trying to install QIIME2 on Linux with the command

```
conda install -c qiime2 qiime2
```

and get this error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.                        failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - qiime2 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']

Your python: python=3.9

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0

Your installed version is: 2.31`
```

I even tried installing it another way using:

```
conda env create -n qiime2 --file qiime2.yml
```

and get another error:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - libgfortran=4.0.0
  - appnope=0.1.0
```

I'm very new to this so any help on how I could maybe solve this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
./conda install -c anaconda appnope
./conda install -c anaconda libgfortran
```